# sound_port.c EC suspended because of inactivity PjSip 2.8 on Android

Tags: android, pjsip

We are developing a Voip-Application for Android using the Pjsip-Framework (Version 2.8 with openssl). On some devices we encounter the following problem:
After successfully establishing a sip call the participants can't hear each other. Whenever this happens the following message appears in the Log:

```
sound_port.c  EC suspended because of inactivity
```

On devices where the participants can hear each other this message is followed by:

```
sound_port.c  EC activated
```

This message does not appear on the affected devices or it appears but with a delay of a minute or even more.

For activating the sound port we use the following code which is the same code that is used in the PjSip Sampleapp:

```java
@Override
public void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam prm) {
    CallInfo ci;
    try {
        ci = getInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }

    CallMediaInfoVector cmiv = ci.getMedia();

    for (int i = 0; i < cmiv.size(); i++) {
       CallMediaInfo cmi = cmiv.get(i);
       if (cmi.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
           (cmi.getStatus() ==  pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE || cmi.getStatus() ==  pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD)) {
                // unfortunately, on Java too, the returned Media cannot be
                // downcasted to AudioMedia
                Media m = getMedia(i);
                AudioMedia am = AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(m);

                // connect ports
                try {
                    MyApp.ep.audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia().
                            startTransmit(am);
                    am.startTransmit(MyApp.ep.audDevManager().
                            getPlaybackDevMedia());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    continue;
                }
        } else if (cmi.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO &&
                    cmi.getStatus() ==  pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE && cmi.getVideoIncomingWindowId() != pjsua2.INVALID_ID) {
                vidWin = new VideoWindow(cmi.getVideoIncomingWindowId());
                vidPrev = new VideoPreview(cmi.getVideoCapDev());
        }
    }
    MyApp.observer.notifyCallMediaState(this);
}
```

Like i said this code seem to work on some devices, on other devices it sadly doesn't (reliably). Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Hi in my case I can hear other parties without any problem even when EC suspended because of inactivity log appear. tried in different devices also. I think this log have nothing to do with your issue :)